# Accessing local computer in browser with company domain suffix

Tags: ios, networking, localhost

I am running web server for my application (Angular) on my work laptop and whenever I want to access it from my laptop I have to go to `https://localhost.company.com:8000/` so that my login cookies are sent to my local proxy server that communicates with development server. This works fine, but I need to access this local server from iPhone devices, but it seems that they don't recognize URL as local IP with suffix. So when I enter `https://192.168.1.100.company.com:8000/` it won't find the server. It will find the server if I omit the `.company.com`, it will load the index file served by server, but it won't send cookies to my proxy endpoint and therefore the app is not working.

Is there a way to access this local server with cookie sending on iPhone/iPad devices?

Comment: You would need to add a DNS record for your local computer so that you can refer to it via a DNS name.

Comment: I can't edit DNS records on our company's DNS server.

Comment: You will need to ask someone to do it. Do direct IP requests not go through the proxy (ie https://192.168.1.100:8000)?